# CreateProcess error=2

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

I tried to run a netbeans platform application from the following link...

https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-quick-start.html

The application runs correctly.When i tried to create an exe file for this application using netbeans,I get the following errors..

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\extide\ant\bin\ant.bat"(in directory "C:\Users\Elcot\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WordProcessor\build\installer\nbi_all\ext\infra\build\engine\build\ext\engine") : CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified.
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(runtime.java:620)
at org.apache.tools.ant.ant.taskdefs.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Java13CommandLauncher.java:58)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:428)
```

and more..

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, the system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.Processimpl.create(Native Method)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
...59 more
BUILD FAILED.
```

Please suggest a way to solve this problem.

Comment: At first glance, it seems like PATH issue. The platform cannot locat the `ant` executable. Do you have `ant` in your PATH environmental variable?

Comment: No, I don't have ant in my PATH environment variable